# How do you swap two local variables within a function in python

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, data-structures

I am trying to swap local variables within a function to rotate a 2 by 2 matrix by 90 degrees.

```
def twobytwo(m):
    last = len(m)-1
    for i in range(0, last):
        swap(m[i][i], m[i][last])
        swap(m[i][i], m[last][last])
        swap(m[i][i], m[last][i])
    return m


def swap(i, j):
    temp = i
    i = j
    j = temp

print(twobytwo([[0, 1], [2, 3]]))
```

Currently, I am returned the original matrix but I want to see

```
[[2,0],[3,1]]
```

Comment: `swap` isn't changing anything in `twobytwo`, because `int`'s aren't mutable.

Comment: @Tomothy32: It wouldn't change anything even if ints were mutable, or if you passed in lists instead of ints. Local variable assignment doesn't mutate objects.

Comment: Any recommendations on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want to achieve:

```
def twobytwo(m):
    last = len(m)-1
    for i in range(0, last):
        m[i][i], m[i][last] = m[i][last], m[i][i]
        m[i][i], m[last][last] = m[last][last], m[i][i]
        m[i][i], m[last][i] = m[last][i], m[i][i]
    return m

print(twobytwo([[0, 1], [2, 3]]))
```

EDIT: 
If you still want to maintain the function `swap`:

```
def swap(i, j):
    return j, i

a, b = swap(a, b)
```

But I think `a, b = b, a` is good enough.

Comment: Thanks so much! Do you by chance know how I would do this if I wanted to use the swap function as well?

Comment: @user9476376 Added additional answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is that the swap() parameters are modified in place (i.e. pass-by-reference). Python does not do that in your code: when you call something like swap(m[i][i], m[i][last]), it dereferences the values of m and calls swap(0,1). So swap() only modifies i,j; it does not modify your "matrix" (which technically is a list of lists).

Try rewriting your swap() function to take the "matrix" plus two pairs of indices: (i,j) and (k,l).

Comment: Python does also not use "pass by value". See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference/986145#986145

Comment: @mkrieger1 : That would be true if you pass an object like m, but the sample code dereferences to int values, which are not objects. Nevertheless, I updated my answer to clear this up.